# NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass- regex confusion

Tags: ruby, comparison

Can someone help me find out why I'm getting this error?

I have an if statement as follows

```
if (x + ship.size) <= 10
```

I retrieve x from the regex expression and back expression:

```
(1,2) =~ /(\d+),(\d+)/
 x, y = $1, $2
```

and I retrieve ship.size from a similar regex expression in a class object.

From my understanding, using \d in both my regex expressions is making ship.size an integer as well as x. Thus, shouldn't + be treated as addition rather than an undefined method? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `(1,2)` is not a string. It should throw an error. What your actual code is?

Comment: @EmilyRivas: This can't be the actual code you have executed, because `(1,2) =~ /(\d+),(\d+)/` would give you a syntax error. Try it in `irb`!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. I should be able to run your code, exactly as you've provided it, and see the same result as you. `(1,2) =~ /(\d+),(\d+)/` is not valid code. Perhaps you meant `"(1,2)" =~ /(\d+),(\d+)/`, but then, that would mean `x == "1"` (not `nil`, but also not an integer!) so it still wouldn't explain your error message.

Comment: And to be clear, the error says that **`x` is `nil`**; it's not nothing to do with `ship` or `ship.size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions operate on strings. Even with `\d` the match will still be a string:

```
"foo123bar"[/\d+/] #=> "123"
#                      ^---^ note the quotes, this is a string
```

If you want an integer, you have to convert the result yourself, e.g. via [`to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#to_i-method):

```
"foo123bar"[/\d+/].to_i #=> 123
#                           ^^^ this is an integer
```

And if no match is found, you'll get `nil`:

```
"fooxyzbar"[/\d+/] #=> nil
```

---

Regarding your error message:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

means that the receiver of `+` was `nil`. In your code:

```
if (x + ship.size) <= 10
```

that receiver is `x`, so `x` is `nil`. You basically have:

```
if (nil + ship.size) <= 10
```

Double-check how you retrieve `x`. Something like this should work:

```
"123,456" =~ /(\d+),(\d+)/

x = $1.to_i #=> 123
y = $2.to_i #=> 456
```